# AngularJS 1.5 component and styling

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a layout generator for flexbox and I'm using AngularJS 1.5.7 components. Basically, my issue is that "replace" does not exist for component but I'd like to be able to dynamically style the root element of my component.

Say that I have a main "div" with its display set on "flex". When I click on a button, it adds a component in this "div" which will be the items of the flexbox layout. The HTML generated is:

```
<div style="display:flex;">
  <item>
    <div style="flex-grow:1;..."></div>
  </item>
</div>
```

My issue is that the styles are applied to the "div" **inside** the "item" element, but "flexbox" does not work as expected as the "item" element does not have any flexbox-related styling. Note that the idea is that I also have some dropdown and textbox used to modify the CSS properties of the "item" component. The template of this one looks like:

```
<div class="zone" data-ng-style="$ctrl.model.getStyle()">
...
</div>
```

And I'm inserting this component like this:

```
<item model="$ctrl.item"></item>
```

Then, my question is: "What's the alternative to 'replace' property of directives?" or "How to dynamically style the root element of the component?".

Thanks

Comment: `component` is supposed to be self-contained widget, web component-alike. Once it is compiled, it should modify its contents, not component element itself. For your case directive is a better choice.

Comment: replace is deprecated for directives as well, so I'm curious how we should resolve the original poster issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was hesitant about using some Angular-only classes such as `.ng-isolate-scope` (due to `.component()` always using isolate scopes), but you could be able to provide styles for your own component:

`item { 
   flex-grow: 1;
}`

If you would like to dynamically apply classes specific to your element, you could follow the same pattern.

`item.selected {
   font-weight: bold;
}`

Nevertheless, I'm not sure about how compliant it could be with older IE versions, though.